# angle bracket mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql, xss, brackets

I have troubles fetching data from a MySQL database when the text inside a VARCHAR field is surrounded by angle brackets ('<' and '>' characters).

Let me be more specific. This is the table from which I'm fetching data:

```
    mysql> describe msgs;
    +---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | partition_tag | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
    | mail_id       | varbinary(16)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    | secret_id     | varbinary(16)       | YES  |     |         |       |
    | am_id         | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | time_num      | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | time_iso      | char(16)            | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | sid           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | policy        | varchar(255)        | YES  |     |         |       |
    | client_addr   | varchar(255)        | YES  |     |         |       |
    | size          | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | originating   | char(1)             | NO   |     |         |       |
    | content       | char(1)             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | quar_type     | char(1)             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | quar_loc      | varbinary(255)      | YES  |     |         |       |
    | dsn_sent      | char(1)             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | spam_level    | float               | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | message_id    | varchar(255)        | YES  | MUL |         |       |
    | from_addr     | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | subject       | varchar(255)        | YES  |     |         |       |
    | host          | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    +---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

    mysql> select * from msgs LIMIT 1;
    +---------------+--------------+--------------+----------+------------+------------------+-----+--------+--------------+------+-------------+---------+-----------+--------------+----------+------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+--------------------+
    | partition_tag | mail_id      | secret_id    | am_id    | time_num   | time_iso         | sid | policy | client_addr  | size | originating | content | quar_type | quar_loc     | dsn_sent | spam_level | message_id                    | from_addr                              | subject | host               |
    +---------------+--------------+--------------+----------+------------+------------------+-----+--------+--------------+------+-------------+---------+-----------+--------------+----------+------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+--------------------+
    |             0 | 0qJcjCXZM8K3 | 7a8Q1_crCzuj | 02085-01 | 1365578237 | 20130410T071717Z |   4 | MYNETS | 172.31.255.5 | 1246 | Y           | V       | Q         | 0qJcjCXZM8K3 | N        |         -1 | <51651189.9080705@test.it>    | User Name <test@test.it>               |  test   |  localhost         |
    +---------------+--------------+--------------+----------+------------+------------------+-----+--------+--------------+------+-------------+---------+-----------+--------------+----------+------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+--------------------+
```

When executing a query via PHP MySQLi interface (eg: SELECT * from msgs), the from_addr field show only the first part (in this case "User Name") but *not* the text inside the angle brackets ("test@test.it", in this case).

At the moment, I worked around it by using a REPLACE statement inside mysql query, substituting the angle brackets with square brackets. However, I would like to know how to correctly query text inside angle brackets.

Thank you all.

Comment: Are you outputting this in a HTML page? Because it'll be interpreted as a HTML tag if you are - it'll show up in the source code. You can do a str_replace on the output to swap `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: use `mysql_real_escape_string()` function, it will help you

Comment: If you're loading this in PHP, look at this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `from_addr` will be there if you are receiving results from your query.

Take a look at this example:

```
$string = '<hello world>';
echo $string;
echo htmlspecialchars('<hello world>');
```

Whereas, `echo $string` will show in the source code, but is being treated as a tag, and therefore not display "on screen".

Using the `htmlspecialchars()` will change `< >` to `&lt; &gt;` which will show "on screen".

It appears that you are using this field for email, so I would NOT recommend saving to the database with `htmlspecialchars`, as you want the emails to send properly.

If the above didn't answer your question fully, and you wish to query the database for an email rather than the "send name", I would recommend using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM `msgs` WHERE `from_addr` LIKE '<%INSERT_EMAIL_ADDRESS%>'.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, problem solved :)

Comment: While I was already using htmlspecialchars to escape special characters, a logic error inside my PHP scripts cause this functions to never be called. Thank you all for your pacience and courtesy.