# select one column value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am facing problem to select data from database in mysql.

my table name  is:
**record**
[image]

my query is:

```
$query = mysql_query(Select `salt` from record where `id` = '1012');
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $row['salt'];
```

my output

> sJ@>L0CeKotpH;kokFo1Z9BwE/ey8(i?nbpQ3ICY;]PRaD7TJE)I3@RYWZTSV]YkO2cduj6eeE0IFGuYE

So please suggest me how to get salt column value from the table.

Comment: 'whole' means? All the value of that row?

Comment: That looks like quite a reasonable value for a 'salt' column to me. Do you know what the 'salt' usually is?

Comment: and `where id =1011`

Comment: Look at the source of your page. The whole salt will be there. It's the `<` that makes the rest disappear in your browser.

Comment: Why cakephp is there as a tag? it's surely not related to cakephp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem should be caused by `echo $row['salt'];`

Your column `salt` has a `<` in its value, so when `echo` it, the string after `<` will be discarded, you can try to run this:

```
<?php
echo 'sJ@>L0CeKotpH;kokFo1Z9BwE/ey8(i?nbpQ3ICY;]PRaD7TJE)I3@RYWZTSV]YkO2cduj6eeE0IFGuYE<R1GZ+OM2`Oto<W\`U:'
?>
```

Then you will find the result is

> sJ@>L0CeKotpH;kokFo1Z9BwE/ey8(i?nbpQ3ICY;]PRaD7TJE)I3@RYWZTSV]YkO2cduj6eeE0IFGuYE

***Edited***:

```
echo htmlspecialchars('sJ@>L0CeKotpH;kokFo1Z9BwE/ey8(i?nbpQ3ICY;]PRaD7TJE)I3@RYWZTSV]YkO2cduj6eeE0IFGuYE<R1GZ+OM2`Oto<W\`U:')
```

Comment: But i need value is:
sJ@>L0CeKotpH;kokFo1Z9BwE/ey8(i?nbpQ3ICY;]PRaD7TJE)I3@RYWZTSV]YkO2cduj6eeE0IFGuYE<R1GZ+OM2`Oto<W\`U:

Comment: @VishnuPratap Use `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: This function work for me.Thanks a lot for the solution.I also did some R&D for this case and found same case in below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977525/angle-bracket-mysql-php?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @VishnuPratap That's great. :D

Answer (score 0):

Replace with bellow line then it will display as you want. But in other operations it will be same as it is.

```
echo str_replace("<","&lt;",$row['salt']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo htmlentities($row['salt']);
```

That should do it.